# How to implement timeline feature using D3/SVG?

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

[image: Timeline image]

I would like to implement this using D3/SVG.
Please help me.

I tried this using react-zoom-pan-pinch module but I don't know how to style this.
I provide sample code.

This code make feature different from above image.
I don't have knowledge about svg so please help me.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from 'react-zoom-pan-pinch';

const Timeline = () => {
    const svgRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);
    const [timelineWidth, setTimelineWidth] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            const svgElement = svgRef.current;
            if (svgElement) {
                const width = svgElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
                setTimelineWidth(width);
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        handleResize();

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };
    }, []);

    const renderRects = () => {
        const rectWidth = 10;
        const rectHeight = 10;
        const rectMargin = 2;
        const numDates = 100;

        const startDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
        const endDate = new Date(2023, 11, 31);

        const dates = generateRandomDates(startDate, endDate, numDates);

        const rects = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < numDates; i++) {
            const x = i * (rectWidth + rectMargin);
            rects.push(
                <g key={i}>
                    <rect
                        x={x}
                        y={10}
                        width={rectWidth}
                        height={rectHeight}
                        fill="steelblue"
                    />
                    <text
                        x={x + rectWidth / 2}
                        y={30}
                        textAnchor="middle"
                        fill="#333"
                        fontSize="8"
                    >
                        1
                        {/* {formatDate(dates[i])} */}
                    </text>
                </g>
            );
        }

        return rects;
    };

    const generateRandomDates = (start: Date, end: Date, count: number) => {
        const dateArray = [];
        const startMillis = start.getTime();
        const endMillis = end.getTime();
        const rangeMillis = endMillis - startMillis;

        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            const randomMillis = startMillis + Math.random() * rangeMillis;
            const date = new Date(randomMillis);
            dateArray.push(date);
        }

        return dateArray;
    };

    const formatDate = (date: any) => {
        const options = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
        return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    };

    return (
        <TransformWrapper>
            <TransformComponent>
                <svg ref={svgRef} width="100%" height="100">
                    <g>
                        {renderRects()}
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </TransformComponent>
        </TransformWrapper>
    );
};

export default Timeline;
```

Please reference above typescript code.